# Why is the Copy app stuck on "downloading file list"?

Tags: windows-8

I have been using the Copy app (from http://www.copy.com) to store and sync files. I recently did a fresh install of Windows 8 on one of my computers, and reinstalled Copy in the process. However, after logging in, it gets stuck at "downloading file list," and never actually downloads any files. (I left it running all night to verify this.) Also, when I try to choose which folders to sync, that list never loads. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I used an old installer from when I had installed Copy originally, under the mistaken impression that it would update automatically if needed. It didn't. Installed a fresh version from the site and the problem was fixed.